# Using discretize filter in weka explorer

Tags: classification, weka

I'm trying to use the discretize filter on my dataset to make the last attribute nominal instead of numeric

I set the attributeIndices field to last
and   the bins field to 3

After I apply the filter the attribute doesn't change to nominal. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there an error message in the Log?

Comment: no there was no error. I found some posts where people where having the same problem, it looks like the filter doesn't work on the class attribute. As a way around the problem, I changed the class attribute, discretized the attribute I needed and then changed it to be the class attribute again

Answer (score 1):

Your last attribute is by default your class attribute, i. e. the one you'll be trying to predict. In order to successfully discretize a class attribute you need to set the `ignoreClass` parameter of your Disretize filter to `true`, otherwise, the discretization won't do anything. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00onr.png).